# QDockWidget -- keep widgets as close as possible when resizing window

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt, qdockwidget, qgroupbox

I have a QDockWidget containing several QGroupBoxes. (The content of the QGroupBoxes is shown/hidden upon mousePressEvent.) I'm looking for a way to keep the QGroupBoxes positioned as tightly together as possible, preferably at the top of the DockWidget. It should look something like this:

[image: desired result]

However, when increasing the size of the DockWidget, the GroupBoxes drift apart:

[image: current result]

...which is very convenient in most cases, I know. But is there a way to override this behavior and get a nice, expandable, list-like grouping of Widgets?

The DockWidget contains a QGroupBox; the QGroupBoxes 'Foo', 'Bar' and 'Baz' are added to that box's QVBoxLayout.

Comment: you can try form layout with sizepolicy maximum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [adding an expanding spacer](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#addStretch) to the end of the vbox:

```
vbox.addStretch()
```